# CakePHP 3-level-deep model associations

Tags: php, cakephp, join, children, pagination

I am relatively new to CakePHP, I am doing fine with the documentation, but I've been trying to find a way out to this problem for weeks and I don't seem to find the solution, I am sure it is easy and maybe even automagically doable, but I just don't know how to find it (maybe I don't know the jargon for these kind of things)

My model structure is like this:

```
<?php
    class Trip extends AppModel {
          var $belongsTo = array(
            'User' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
            ),
            'Start' => array(
                'className' => 'Place',
                'foreignKey' => 'start_id'
            ),
            'End' => array(
                'className' => 'Place',
                'foreignKey' => 'end_id'
            ),
            'Transport' => array(
                'className' => 'Transport',
                'foreignKey' => 'transport_id'
            )
        );

     }
?>

<?php
class Place extends AppModel {

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ),
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id'
        ),
        'State' => array(
            'className' => 'State',
            'foreignKey' => 'state_id'
        ),
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
        )
    );
    var $hasMany = array(
        'PlaceStart' => array(
            'className' => 'trip',
            'foreignKey' => 'start_id',
            'dependent' => false
        ),
        'PlaceEnd' => array(
            'className' => 'trip',
            'foreignKey' => 'end_id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );

}
?>

<?php
class State extends AppModel {

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

    var $hasMany = array(
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'foreignKey' => 'city_id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );

}
?>
```

... and so forth with User, City, Country, and Transport Models.

What I am trying to achieve is to get all the information of the whole tree when I search for a `Trip`.

```
<?php
class TripController extends AppController {
    function index() {
        debug($this->Trip->find('first'));
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [Trip] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [created] => 2010-05-04 00:23:59
            [user_id] => 4
            [start_id] => 2
            [end_id] => 1
            [title] => My trip
            [transport_id] => 1
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => John Doe
            [email] => john.doe@mailinator.com
        )

    [Start] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 4
            [country_id] => 1
            [state_id] => 1
            [city_id] => 1
            [direccion] => Lincoln Street
        )

    [End] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 4
            [country_id] => 1
            [state_id] => 1
            [city_id] => 4
            [address] => Fifth Avenue
        )

    [Transport] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => car
        )
)
```

Here is the question:
**How do I get in one query all the information down the tree?**

I would like to have something like

```
Array
(
    [Trip] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [created] => 2010-05-04 00:23:59
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => John Doe
                    [email] => john.doe@mailinator.com
                )
            [Start] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [Country] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] = Spain
                        )
                    [State] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] = Barcelona
                        )
                    [City] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] = La Floresta
                        )
                    [address] => Lincoln Street
                )
            [End] => (same as Start)
            [title] => My trip
            [Transport] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => car
                )
        )
)
```

Can CakePHP create this kind of data? 
Not only for `$this->Model->find()` but also for `$this->paginate()` as for example:

```
    // filter by start
    if(isset($this->passedArgs['start'])) {
        //debug('isset '.$this->passedArgs['start']);
        $start = $this->passedArgs['start'];
        $this->paginate['conditions'][] = array(
            'OR' => array(
                'Start.address LIKE' => "%$start%",
                'Start.State.name LIKE' => "%$start%",
                'Start.City.name LIKE' => "%$start%",
                'Start.Country.name LIKE' => "%$start%"
            )
        );
        $this->data['Search']['start'] = $start;
    }
```

It seems like a rough question but I am sure this is extensively done and documented, I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have everything setup OK. All you should have to do is set the recursive to 2 and that should give you an extra level to your data (assuming that you have set up all the relations correctly)

```
var $recursive =2;
```

Comment: Or `$this->Trip->find('first', array('recursive' =>  2));`

Comment: Simply beautiful. Thanks a milion paullb and bancer!

Comment: this seems like it could be awesome, but - with a lot of associations, I can't use recursive 2 without getting memory errors - even if I limit it to one result (like 'first').  Any ideas?

Comment: You could dynamically bind on the associates you need at runtime rather than having them set up permanently in the model. (You could even set up functions in the model to set up the binding for you so it's all in one place)

Comment: If anybody using CakePHP 3.0 comes across this answer, I just learned that `recursive` has been abandoned and so you should use `contain()` instead. More information here: [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html#recursive-and-containablebehavior-removed)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, more surgical, solution that's particularly useful if you need to go deeper than 2 levels or if you have a lot of 2nd level associations that you don't need for this particular problem is the [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable). This is the 1.2.x documentation. If you're using v1.3.x, you'll find it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable).